# Customize a particular item in the listbox on windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox

I am using a listbox with a customized ItemTemplate style. It basically attach a button with each item in listbox. I want to show the last item in thge list box without button. How can i accomplish it?

.xaml file code is given below.

```
     <!-- ListBox to display recordings -->
        <ListBox Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="0"                     
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="470"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  
                 ScrollViewer.ManipulationMode="System"
                 SelectionChanged="OnMemosListBoxSelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                Padding="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="top"
                                Height="80"
                                Width="80"
                                Tag="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}"
                                Click="OnDeleteButtonClick">                                    
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Source="/images/delete.png" Margin="0" Width="50" Height="50" />
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                                   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"
                                   Grid.Row="0"
                                   Text="{Binding fileName}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,17"
                                    Grid.Row="1" Height="50" 
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top">

                            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Text="Recorded on " />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" Text="{Binding crDate}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="   Duration " />
                            <TextBlock FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"  Text="{Binding duration}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: did you get any solution, I am also facing the same problem. In my case I want to disable the tap for particular items in listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property, e.g. ShowButton to all your items, set it to false for the last item (true for all other items) in the collection and then in your DataTemplate show the button only when the proprerty is true

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why the last item of list does not need that button , but i suggest to you, you can use longlistselector's ListFooterTemplate.

make footer item be independent.